# Issue in Format Specifiers of C

Tags: c, format-specifiers

How is `%+8.9d` different from `%8.9d` in C?

Let's take an example

```
int a=444;

float b=444;

printf("%8.9d",a);
printf("%8.9f",b);
printf("%+8.9d",a);
printf("%+8.9f",b);
```

Output:

```
000000444
444.000000000
+000000444
+444.000000000
```

Why are 6 zeros present before the number? (that too only in integer numbers)

**What is significance of + here?**

How is `+` getting printed in the output?

Comment: https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/ _"Forces to preceed the result with a plus or minus sign (+ or -) even for positive numbers. By default, only negative numbers are preceded with a - sign."_

Comment: Re "*why are 9 digits present before the number?*", huh??? What are you talking about?

Comment: @ikegami  sorry ,it's6 0's present before the number

Comment: Without any newlines all the results are run together in a single line.

Comment: @WeatherVane yeah i have modified the output for better vision

Comment: What I meant, is that the output you show cannot have been made by that code, because it does not output newlines, and all the characters will be on a single line all run together.

Comment: @WeatherVane  so it can be `"% .9d"` also haa ??? is their no significance for `"8"` here can it replaced by any number  ???

Comment: `8` is the field width. If the output is greater than the field width, it overflows, because it it were truncated the worse evil would be an incorrect number seen. You told it to output 9 digits precison, so 9 are shown and the `8` is ignored. But if you had `%10.9d` then there would be a space in front of the output.

Comment: @WeatherVane got it ...Thanks !!!

Comment: @WeatherVane the field width what you said is it only for integers ???? coz if i put `%10.9f` their is no difference [ that is their  is no space in front of output ]
    so  for float and double numbers does it all means the same......................................so can we say " `%x.9 f` [ x being any number] is same as .9 for float and double data types"  ???????????

Comment: In the case of the `%f` specifier the precision is the number of decimal places. `%10.9f` means a field with of 10 and 9 decimal places. Obviously that isn't possible and the whole number is output. So you "might as well" omit the field width, as put a nonsensical value which is going to be ignored such as in your `%8.9d`

Comment: @WeatherVane ohh yeah ... thank you  !!!! 

Comment: @WeatherVane why is this happening ???........`A=1.2345`  ....`printf("%09.3f", A); A=00001.234`
`printf("%-09.3f", A); A=1.234` .......In the second one why is "-" sign creating a difference ??? please help me this last issue!!!!!

Comment: `"%-09.3f"` means "left justify in a field width of 9 with leading zeros and 3 decimal places". The default is to right-justify. But your instruction is contradictory: if it is left-justified, it can't be output with leading zeros. They would be relevant if you *right* justify, using zeros padding instead of spaces. Please spend an hour reading about formats. They are complicated.

Comment: @WeatherVane  yeah will definitely spend some time on these formats   and Thanks a lot for giving your time ....

Answer (score 2):

> *Why are 6 zeros present before the number?*

You requested for a minimum of 9 digits to appear (when printing the `int`).

Quote https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf,

> (optional) `.` followed by integer number or `*`, or neither that specifies *precision* of the conversion. In the case when `*` is used, the *precision* is specified by an additional argument of type `int`, which appears before the argument to be converted, but after the argument supplying minimum field width if one is supplied. If the value of this argument is negative, it is ignored. If neither a number nor `*` is used, the precision is taken as zero. See the table below for exact effects of *precision*.

From the referenced table, for `d`:

> *Precision* specifies the minimum number of digits to appear. The default precision is `1`. If both the converted value and the precision are ​0​ the conversion results in no characters.

---

> *How is `+` getting printed in the output?*

You requested for a the sign of the number to appear.

Quote https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf,

> `+`: the sign of signed conversions is always prepended to the result of the conversion (by default the result is preceded by minus only when it is negative)